# TabActivity is Deprecated in Android 4.0 (Ice cream sandwich)

Tags: android, tabs, deprecated

I am having a problem with android 4.0 that is

> TabActivity in android is deprecated

Then how can we build a project with Tab?

Is Fragment is the right option or it can replace the use of Tabs?
Any suggestion, tutorial or code.
Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: As to your first question, yes, fragments is the right replacement. From the docs; This class is deprecated.
New applications should use Fragments instead of this class; to continue to run on older devices, you can use the v4 support library which provides a version of the Fragment API that is compatible down to DONUT.

Comment: great, what is v4 support library??

Comment: See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563351/how-to-add-ui-tabs-in-this-new-ics-world

Comment: Nice find @Vamsi, didn't find that when searching :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the usage of TabActivity has been deprecated since android 3.0. From now on fragments are supposed to be used. The android compatibility library is a standalone library in the form of a jar file which can be included in projects. This library makes available the api's for fragments and other new functions introduced in Honeycomb for devices with os version less than 3.0. With the compatibility library fragments can be implmented from android 1.5 upwards.

Comment: hey but I want to make an app, that will use the tabs exactly like the tabs in android2.2 or others. so please tell me is this possible??

Comment: it is possible. You just need to style it. There is already demos about this in compatibility library folder in your android sdk.